# Sidebar closes when deleting element of array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile-angular-ui

I'm using mobile angular ui to open and close a sidebar. In this sidebar a user can search for persons and add or remove these from an array.

I have this repeat that shows the array of persons when clicking on the `<a ...></>` it closes the sidebar:

```
<li ng-repeat="recipient in persons.recipients">
    <span class="wrapper">
        <span class="imageWrap">
            <span class="initials">
                {{recipient.firstName.charAt(0)}}{{recipient.lastName.charAt(0)}} </span>
        </span>
        <a href="" class="trash" ng-click="removeRecipient($index);"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <span class="details">
            <span class="info">
                {{recipient.firstName}} {{recipient.lastName}}
                <span class="persnr">{{recipient.employeeID}}</span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</li>
```

The above html snippet is from a directive that is in the sidebar.
The `removeRecipient($index);` function looks like this:

```
$scope.removeRecipient = function(index) {
    $scope.persons.recipients.splice(index,1);
}
```

The function works but closes the sidebar and I can't figure out why it does this. So each time a user removes a recipient it has to swipe the sidebar open again. How do I keep this sidebar open?

References:

- mobile angular ui: http://mobileangularui.com/docs/sidebars/

**SOLUTION**

I solved my problem by adding `$event.stopPropagation();` in the `ng-click` right behind the `removeRecipient($index);` function.

Comment: Are you using `ui-toggle` in the sidebar `a` tags?

Comment: I'm not using `ui-toggle` in the sidebar `a` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From doc, there was one line.

> You can put ui-turn-off='uiSidebarLeft' or ui-turn-off='uiSidebarLeft'
>   inside the sidebar to make it close after clicking links inside them.

so may be you can use that or you can use or you can do like below.

```
e.stopPropagation()
```

for that you need to pass $event in

```
<a href="" class="trash" ng-click="removeRecipient($index,$event);"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

so in code, you can write.

```
$scope.removeRecipient = function(index,e) {
    if(e){
        e.stopPropagation()
    }
    $scope.persons.recipients.splice(index,1);
}
```

I didn't used same tool, but may be this is issue.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I tried these solutions before and neither of them worked.

Comment: Ok so I searched further after stopping the `$event` and found this line : `$event.stopPropagation();`. It solved my problem. I will count your answer as correct because it was close.

Comment: yes.. sorry i forgot about stopPropagation. I will update answer